# Show that there exists a coordinate system in $\mathbb{P}^n$ such that $P_0=(1:0:\cdots:0),\ldots,P_n=(0:0:\cdots:1),P_{n+1}=(1:\cdots:1)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

> **Proposition**: Let $P_0,\ldots,P_{n+1}$ be $n+2$ points in $\mathbb{P}^n$ such that every $n+1$ are in general position. There exists a coordinate system in $\mathbb{P}^n$ such that $P_0=(1:0:\cdots:0),\ldots,P_n=(0:0:\cdots:1),P_{n+1}=(1:\cdots:1)$.

I found a proof but I have some doubts. Let me write it.

**Proof**: Fix a homogeneous coordinate system in $\mathbb{P}^n$. Denote $P_k=(a_0^k:\cdots:a_n^k)$ for every $k=0,\ldots,n$. Denote $u_k=(a_0^k,\cdots,a_n^k) \in \mathbb{K}^{n+1}$. As $P_0,\ldots,P_n$ are in general position, $\{u_0,\ldots,u_n\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{K}^{n+1}$. Then $u_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^n \alpha_k u_k$ with $\alpha_k \neq 0$ for all $k$. Hence in the basis $\{\alpha_0 u_0,\ldots,\alpha_n u_n\}$ of $\mathbb{K}^{n+1}$, the homogeneous coordinates of each $P_k$ is what is given in the proposition.

**My doubts**:

1. Why is $\alpha_k \neq 0$ for all $k$? Is anything about the general position? **[Closed]**
2. More or less I understand why $\{\alpha_0 u_0,\ldots,\alpha_n u_n\}$ is the required basis. Formally we have
   $$(1,0,\ldots,0)=1 \cdot \alpha_0 u_0 = \alpha_0(a_0^0,\ldots,a_n^0)$$
   $$\vdots$$
   $$(0,\ldots,0,1)=1 \cdot \alpha_n u_n = \alpha_n(a_0^n,\ldots,a_n^n)$$
   $$(1,\ldots,1)=1 \cdot \alpha_0 u_0 + \cdots + 1 \cdot \alpha_n u_n = u_{n+1} = (a_0^{n+1},\ldots,a_n^{n+1})$$
   Is this enough to show the last sentence of the proof?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. $u_0,\dots,u_n$ is a basis for $\mathbb K^n$, and $u_{n+1}$ is a non-zero vector (by definition of homogeneous coordinates in $\mathbb P^n$).

Comment: @Donkey_2009 You are stating that all the $\alpha_k$ cannot be 0, not that each $\alpha_k$ is nonzero

Comment: The condition is that no $n+1$ of these lie on a hyperplane. Try to contradict this.

Comment: @Hoot Thanks. I get the idea.